# Where are Galois's notes?

Tags: galois-theory

There are a number of photos of bits of Galois's notes floating around online, such as [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/40213/40213-pdf.pdf?session_id=cacdcb683f105e0d90ea81986953ab5c38da2848) and [here](https://www.storyofmathematics.com/19th_galois.html). But where are they, physically? I'm hoping what remained of them wasn't tossed out once photos were taken.

Comment: [Link to question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459866/where-are-galoiss-notes/3459929#3459929).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the Library of  l'Institut de France that is [Bibliotheque de L'Institut de France](https://rhpst.huma-num.fr/items/show/122): "285 feuillets en 27 dossiers. Formats divers. Demi-reliure." There is a research tool [online.](http://www.calames.abes.fr/pub/#details?id=IF2B14057)